# In an equilateral triangle RST, points K, L, M are located on the sides such that RK=SL=TM. Prove that triangle KLM is equilateral.

Tags: geometry, proof-writing

In an equilateral triangle ***RST***, points ***K, L, M*** are located on the sides such that **RK=SL=TM**.

Prove that triangle ***KLM*** is equilateral.

---

I have been trying to conduct this proof, but I can't seem to figure out how to show that ***KLM*** is equilateral. So far I understand that since triangle ***RST*** is equilateral, ***RK=SL=TM*** and ***SK=LT=MR***. I have been trying to figure out how to use ASA or SAS congruence to prove the statement. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The description is unclear as to where exactly $K$, $L$, $M$ lie. Your discussion suggests that $K$ is on $\overline{RS}$, $L$ is on $\overline{ST}$, and $M$ is on $\overline{TR}$. Is that your intention?

Comment: @Blue Yes, sorry I was unclear in my post. Your assumptions are correct.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. Observe that $\triangle KSL \cong \triangle LTM \cong \triangle MRK$ through SAS rule as

- **Side:** $\overline{KS} = \overline{LT} = \overline{MR}$
- **Angle:** $\angle KSL = \angle LTM = \angle MRK = 60 ^\circ$
- **Side:** $\overline{SL} = \overline{TM} = \overline{RK}$

Therefore, $\overline{KL}=\overline{LM}=\overline{MK} \implies \triangle{KLM}$ is equilateral.